# How to run a criterion benchmark for a monadic function

Tags: haskell, microbenchmark

With the [criterion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-1.2.2.0/docs/Criterion-Main.html) library I want to benchmark functions with a type of `Monad m => a -> m b`.

Here is a typical example with the *JSM* monad from the [jsaddle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle) library:

```
import           Criterion.Main
import           JSDOM.Types (JSM)
import           GHCJS.Buffer (Buffer(..))
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS (ByteString)

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain [
  bgroup "Image" [ bench "buildBS"  $ nf buildBS 256
                 , bench "toJsBuff" $ nfIO (toJsBuff img)
                 ] ]

img :: BS.ByteString
img = id $! buildBS 256

buildBS :: Int -> BS.ByteString
buildBS = undefined

toJsBuff :: BS.ByteString -> JSM Buffer
toJsBuff bs = undefined
```

Now this does not compile because the function `nfIO` works only for the IO monad and not for any monad.

How can I benchmark such a monadic function?

Note: There is also a compile time error when I use `nf` instead of `nfIO`.

Comment: The more fundamental issue here is that you have to have a notion of what it means for something to be "evaluated" in your monad. In a lot of cases, `nf` may be all you want.

Comment: You'll need to turn your `JSM` computation into an `IO` one using [`runJSM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/jsaddle-dom-0.9.2.0/docs/JSDOM-Types.html#v:runJSM). From reading the docs I can't figure out how you're supposed to call `runJSM` - it needs a `JSContextRef` argument but I can't see any way to get hold of one. Hopefully this is a good enough pointer for you though.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I cannot figure out how to get a `JSContextRef` either. The docs for this library could really use some work.

Comment: Just found it in `Language.Javascript.JSaddle.Null`. The function is named `run`.

Comment: @AndrewThaddeusMartin Good find! I wouldn't have though to look there, it's a very strange module name. I think that would make a good answer.